# How to switch the datasource dynamically at runtime using AbstractRoutingDataSource?

Tags: spring, hibernate, datasource

Requirement:

I have the requirement like to switch the datasource at runtime after receiving the request.

I had read the blog about routing the datasource at runtime in spring3 using the class AbstractRoutingDataSource. Using that we can get the manually defined datasource key's at runtime.

Here in my project, datasources had configured in jetty-env.xml file. Now, i want to retrieve the Database name from DB in some tables like app_config.Using that DB name, i want to switch the database at runtime and also i want to pass the parameters to jetty-env.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Even I have a problem trying to set datasources from DB. You may like my solution (with annotations instead of xml). [Spring 3.1.3 + Hibernate Configuration with annotations and with (Dynamic) AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766111/spring-3-1-3-hibernate-configuration-with-annotations-and-with-dynamic-abstr)

Taking a look at the "EDIT", you can set there any number of static datasources you want) or use them in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new subclass of DriverManagerDataSource, and autowire it a DAO to access table app_config.

Then for example override getUrl() method, and construct the url using a code dbNameParameter that allows to retrieve the database name from app config:

```
<bean id="parentDataSource"
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.custom.MyDriverManagerDataSource"
         abstract="true">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
   <property name="username" value="sa"/>
</bean>

<bean id="goldDataSource" parent="parentDataSource">
   <property name="dbNameParameter" value="gold"/>
</bean>
```

jetty-env.xml is not meant for that use and is better not used on this use case. It's better to put in jetty-env.xml only the datasource for where table app_config is.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the tenant identifier in a ThreadLocal, supply data source list, configure an `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to select the data source at run time based on the tenant identifier.